# Bar plot 4 variables

Tags: r

I have a question regarding bar plots in R. I have a dataset with 4 variables (Month, Year, Location and Number of Births) with 12 different months, 3 different years and 4 different locations.

```
Month Birth Year Location
Jan   3     2017  A
Feb   6     2017  A
Mar   8     2017  A
Apr   9     2017  A
```

Is it possible to create a bar plot with 4 graphs (each one for one year) and within them x-axis=Month, y-axis=Births, per location. Grouped or stack bar plot is the same for me.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `ggplot2` and then use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  Month = rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), 4),
  Birth = c(1:12),
  Year = c(rep("2017", 3), rep("2018", 3),rep("2017", 3), rep("2018", 3)),
  Location = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6))
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Month, y=Birth)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = 'stack', aes(fill = Location)) +
  facet_grid(~Year)
```

[image]

Created on 2021-04-28 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)